Why is the 3rd structure not more stable than the given example?

In the third structure it has same number of alpha H but if we break the bond, then one degree carboanion will be formed, which is more stable than 2 degree of carboanion in the given example. then why?

These sorting exercises are a nightmare! It's almost always the authors intention to test the ability to apply a useless rule. Sur there are the same number of alpha-hydrogens, but what does that mean and what does that imply. I don't even want to start on what stability is actually meant here. Most authors seem to confuse that with the absence of reactivity. And for the love of science, can they please start to write consistent structural representations. This has nothing to do with your question and I applaud your curiosity; unfortunately these exercises make you dumber.

I think instead of carbanion stability, ring strain would be a factor contributing to the stability of given alkenes.
The cyclopentane system imposes steric and angle strain on the double bond. In the given example, the provided alkene could benefit from a more favorable geometry that reduces steric hindrance, which affects overall stability.
So, even if the carbanion formed by the third structure is more stable than  the one formed by the given example, that factor is not much taken into consideration in this case as carbanion stability doesn't contribute to corresponding alkene stability.
Hence, it can be said that the third structure is not more stable than the given example.

It should be the most substituted double bond, so first structure is the most stable among all given structures.
